# Access 2010 - Missing Security Profile

Tags: ms-access

I have some access applications that connect to a SQL Server database.  The applications were written for Access 2003 and now are running on 2010.  We are now getting this message:
[image]

It say "Missing Security Profile" No Security Profile has been set up.  If I click OK then the application runs fine.

Comment: I get the warning in both Access 2010 and 2003.  Could it be the result of a recent Office update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like it may be to do with [user level security](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-user-level-security-mdb-HP003070410.aspx) having been set up at some stage. You might also check that `...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Access` contains a file `system.mdw` (Vista/Windows 7). This is the default security file and is referenced in the connect string in Access 2010.